# Init Dodecahedron array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to init an array that looks like the following Dodecahedron:
[image]

Index 0 can moved to 2,18,19

Index 1 can moved to 5,17,18

etc..

I'm trying to Init the array in for loop as follow:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROOMS; i++)
{
    //?
}
```

But I dont know how can i init the array, I.e:

```
arr[0] = new Indexes(2,18,19);//The indexes that we can moved from index 0
arr[1] = new Indexes(5,17,18);//The indexes that we can moved from index 1
arr[2] = new Indexes(0,4,17);//The indexes that we can moved from index 2
```

How can I do it in the for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `Dodecahedron` already represented as some data structure (e.g. graph)?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates).

Comment: @ΔλЛ, No, I need to implement it with simple array

Comment: What is the input format of your data?

Comment: I just need to know what is the next 3 steps that i can do from index, my input format is Int

Comment: What is a reason for such vertex numbering?

Comment: @MBo The vertex labelling is probably just arbitrary, although it looks a little like this scheme : http://hrcak.srce.hr/index.php?lang=en&show=clanak&id_clanak_jezik=4223 where labels for neighbours are picked from the largest remaining ones

Comment: @Evyatar - It seems like you are just asking how to make an adjacency list representation of a graph. That is, for each vertex (say : 2) a list of neighbours (0, 4, 7). I wouldn't call this an algorithm problem - what language is this; Java?

Comment: @gilleain, It it C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General formula for neighbors of k-th node:

```
 19 - k;
 (k + t) mod 20;
 (k - t + 20) mod 20;
```

where

```
 t = 2 + 2 * (k and 1)   //2 for even, 4 for odd
```